# Top-align beamer from .sty

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I know I can top-align all frames by writing

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
```

However, I am creating a theme for my department. Is there a way I can pass this option from the .sty-file?

Comment: You are creating a `.sty` rather than a `.cls`? You might consider making it a class because you can then say `\LoadClass[t]{beamer}`. Just make sure that you pass options to the `beamer` class if people are allowed to use them!

Comment: @cfr I started making the theme by looking at the source for the university's theme, which was created as a '.sty'. I will definitely consider '.cls' now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `\beamer@centeredfalse` to your .sty file might do the trick

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\beamer@centeredfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        we
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set it up as a class, `dept-beamer`, say, then you can simply pass the options you need to `beamer` along with any the user declares:

```
% dept-beamer.cls
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dept-beamer}% if class is dept-beamer.cls
...
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}% pass options we don't know about off to beamer for processing so e.g. handout etc. will still work
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass[t]{beamer}% load class with departmental options
...
\endinput

% end of dept-beamer.cls
```